# ¿Por qué la salida por pantalla del mensaje de error de mi constructor es "No match found" en vez del mensaje que yo he establecido? (JAVA)

Tags: java, regex, excepciones

He creado utilizando el lenguaje java una clase que valida que un DNI cumpla con un formato/patrón de entrada específico y también valida que la letra del DNI se corresponda con la numeración, entre otras cosas.

Cuando intento crear un DNI no válido que falla porque la letra no corresponde con la numeración, por ejemplo el DNI 12345678a, me sale por pantalla el mensaje de error que he determinado en el constructor "DNI inválido", pero cuando lo que falla es que el String no cumple con el patrón, por ejemplo el DNI 12345678 -z, me sale por pantalla el mensaje "No match found".

No sé cuál es el problema, he pensado que quizás tenga que usar un tipo de excepción más específico para que aparezca mi mensaje, pero mi conociento es limitado en este campo en este momento, y por mucho que he buscado alguna ayuda no he encontrado nada.

En el main utilizo la estructura try-catch al crear un objeto DNI para contemplar las excepciones:

```
try {
      DNI dniObjeto = new DNI(dni);
      System.out.println("  \"" + dni + "\" es correcto. DNI generado: \"" + dniObjeto.toString() + "\"\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("  \"" + dni + "\" NO es correcto. DNI no generado: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
```

Aquí dejo la parte del codigo de la clase sobre la que tengo dudas:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DNI {

  // Atributos
  private long numeracion;
  private char letra;

  // Constructor teniendo en cuenta las excepciones de DNI inválido
  public DNI(String dni) throws Exception {
    boolean dniValido = validar(dni);
    if (dniValido == false) {
      throw new Exception("DNI inválido");
    }
    this.letra = extraeLetra(dni);
    this.numeracion = extraeNumeracion(dni);
  }

  // Método para comprobar que el DNI sea válido, tanto su formato como su letra
  private boolean validar(String dni) {
    boolean dniFormatoValido;
    boolean letraValida;
    int resto;
    String letrasValidasDNI;
    char letraReal;
    // Comprobación de que el dni cumple el formato de entrada adecuado
    Pattern patronDni = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,8})([\\-]|[\\s])?([A-HJ-NP-TV-Za-hj-np-tv-z])");
    Matcher mDni = patronDni.matcher(dni);
    dniFormatoValido = mDni.matches();
    // Extracción de la numeración y de la letra
    String numeracionString = mDni.group(1);
    String letraString = mDni.group(3);
    // Conversión de la numeración a int
    int numeracionDni = Integer.valueOf(numeracionString);
    // Cálculo del resto de la numeración entre 23 para obtener la letra que le correspende a dicha numeración
    resto = numeracionDni % 23;
    // Conversión de la letra a mayúsculas y a tipo char
    char letraDni = letraString.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    // Obtención de la letra que corresponde a la numeración
    letrasValidasDNI = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
    letraReal = letrasValidasDNI.charAt(resto);
    // Comprobación de que la letra introducida es la que corresponde a la numeración
    letraValida = (letraReal == letraDni);
    return dniFormatoValido == true && letraValida == true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Posiblemente el error `No match found` sea arrojado por la clase `Matcher` a la hora de intentar buscar la letra que mencionas.

Comment: Efectivamente, al hacer un debug, sale de ahí, pero no sé como hacer que en vez de ese mensaje de error, use el mio.

Comment: despues de `dniFormatoValido = mDni.matches();` podrias colocar `if (!mDni.matches()) {throw new Exception("DNI inválido");}`  esto porque tu regex valida 8 numeros del 1 al 9 seguido de espacio o guion pero como pones espacio -z nose llega a cumplir el regex por eso lanza match no found

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, podría ser una solución pero no tengo la libertad de cambiar el nombre del método añadiendole throws Exception por cuestiones del enunciado del ejercico que estoy resolviendo.

Comment: evita lanzar errores en el constructor, no se por que pero se ha manejado por años que es una buena practica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me costo encontrar el problema, en el método validar, están las siguientes lineas:

```
Pattern patronDni = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,8})([\\-]|[\\s])?([A-HJ-NP-TV-Za-hj-np-tv-z])");
Matcher mDni = patronDni.matcher(dni);
dniFormatoValido = mDni.matches();
// Extracción de la numeración y de la letra
String numeracionString = mDni.group(1);
String letraString = mDni.group(3);
```

Así como está, te lanza una excepción, la forma correcta es:

```
Pattern patronDni = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,8})([\\-]|[\\s])?([A-HJ-NP-TV-Za-hj-np-tv-z])");
Matcher mDni = patronDni.matcher(dni);
// Extracción de la numeración y de la letra
String letraString = "";
String numeracionString = "";
if( mDni.find()) {
    numeracionString = mDni.group(1);
    letraString = mDni.group(3);
}
dniFormatoValido = mDni.matches();
```

No se bien porque falla, lo que se, es que si intentas usar el método group si colocar el if, lanza la excepción, todos los ejemplos que busque, lo usan así, entonces debe ser una condición del lenguaje, aunque seguro que alguno de nuestros colegas más experimentados, nos sacará de dudas.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu respuesta, el try catch lo uso en el main al usar el constructor porque el método constructor tiene throws Exception. ¿Entonces debería usar otro try catch dentro de validar al usar el matches? Si el método validar solo tiene que comprobar el matches del patrón funciona bien, devuelve false y en pantalla aparece mi mensaje de excepcion, pero al tener que comprobar las dos cosas, no aparece.

Comment: @Sadema ya encontré el error... correjí y funciona

Comment: Lo he probado y he escrito los resultados en otro comentario, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, de verdad.

Comment: @Sadema, tienes razón, me equivoqué, debía hacer declarado las variables fuera del **if**, de hecho, cuando lo probe, lo hice... en fin en vez de declararlas a **null**, puedes iniciarlas como vacias con **""**.

Answer (score 0):

He probado [la respuesta](/a/576888) de [*Marce Puente*](/users/41421) y no me ha funcionado: me ha dado error de compilación al crear los dos String dentro del if y tener que usarlos después aquí.

```
int numeracionDni = Integer.valueOf(numeracionString);

char letraDni = letraString.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```

He creado los String antes, fuera del if, para que no diera ese error, pero los he tenido que inicializar a null para que no me saliera otro error más en las mismas líneas de código que puse arriba, y al final en pantalla el mensaje de error que me sale es "null".

Comment: Poner todo dentro del if (mDni.find())  hace que funcione perfectamente, muchisísimas gracias @Marce Puente :)

Comment: excelente solución.

Comment: Las respuestas deben ir dirigidas a _todos_, no a un usuario en particular. Lee [answer]. Por cierto, pulsa en [edit] y agrega lo último que has mencionado en tu comentario. Tal como está redacta actualmente, esto más bien parece ser una _no-respuesta_.